# Switching between Apps on Guest MacOS, on MacBook Air (MacOS Sierra like Host), Virtualbox

Tags: macos, virtualbox, application-switcher

I have both **MacOS Sierra 10.12** for Host and for Guest using **VirtualBox 5.1.10**

I want to know how switch between applications on MacOS guest Side.

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> On Guest Side, but is taken like Host Side, and change Guest to another application opened Host Side.

How can I configure.

I have **Windows 10** and **CentOS 7** like Guest too, and they works perfectly with <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, but for MacOS guest I can't find.

How configure combination for MacOS Guest and another combination for MacOS Host, to switch between their opened applications respectively?

Thank you.

Comment: Could you rephrase this? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Oh my English is confused!

Comment: I think what the OP is saying is that when they're in the _guest_ version of MacOS Sierra and they use the Cmd + Tab Keyboard shortcut, instead of the shortcut cycling through the apps running **within** the MacOS Sierra 'guest', the shortcut is cycling through the apps open in the MacOS Sierra _host_. And, while this is happening, the guest version of MacOS Sierra is being treated as just another app running on the host.